# How to showing Group in Table ( Angular 6 above)

Tags: html, json, angular, html-table, grouping

I want to ask, if I have a flat sales data in Json format :

```
[ {Amir,Adidas,36,2},{Amir,Nike,30,2},{Amir,Puma,37,3},
  {{Meta,Adidas,41,1},{Meta,Nike,33,2},Meta, Puma,42,4},{Meta, Puma,43,3}  
  {Samsi,Adidas,40,1},Samsi,Nike,31,1},{Bulma,Puma,41,3} ]
```

and the data already sorted by Sales Name, Product Name, shoes no, and Name.

```
+---------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
| Nama                | Adidas       |  Nike        |   Puma            | 
|                     +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|                     | 36 | 40 | 41 | 30 | 31 | 33 | 37 | 41 | 42 | 43 | 
+---------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| Amir                |  2 |    |    |  2 |    |    |  3 |    |    |    |
| Meta                |    |    | 1  |    |    | 2  |    |    |  4 |  3 |
| Samsi               |    |  1 |    |    |  1 |    |    | 3  |    |    |    
+---------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+--- +----+----+
```

How to  make HTML table to present the data, like above.
I am using angular 6 as front end.

Thank You